# LINQ - What does (x, i) do?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda, anonymous-function

I stumbled across this code today and realized I don't understand it what-so-ever.

```
someArray.Select((x, i) => new XElement("entry",
                            new XElement("field", new XAttribute("name", "Option"), i + 1)
```

What is the point of `(x, i)`? I see a reference to the `i`, but I'm not understanding how the `x` fits into this lamda expression.

Also, why is `i` an integer? I see towards the end there is an `i + 1`, so I'm assuming that's true.

Thanks for your help

Comment: That's the lambda function definition.

Comment: and you do see it... `i + 1`.. well, I see it.

Comment: @SamAxe I should've specified that I meant the `x` and not the `i`

Comment: That depends on what the code's trying to do. It looks like it's building a list of XML elements the same length as the original array. I've seen people do this sort of thing when they need a new list the same length as the original one, although you could equally use `Enumerable.Range(0, someArray.Length).Select(i => ...)`. It depends on the context - what do you then do with the list of XML elements? Can you ask whoever wrote it in the first place?

Comment: The code only wants the `i`. The only [overload of `Select` that provides the `i`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) also provides the `x`. So the code has to declare the `x` too even though it's not using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `x` is the value, and the `i` is the index.

For example, the snippet:

```
void Main()
{
    var values = new List<int> {100, 200, 300};
    foreach( var v in values.Select((x, i) => (x, i))) // x is the value, i is the index
        Console.WriteLine(v);
}
```

prints out:

> (100, 0) (200, 1) (300, 2)

The Microsoft [documentation is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__)

Answer (score 4):

It's there because the expression wanted to use the index of the element, which is the second parameter of the lambda expression, `i`. The other overload of `Select`, the one in which the `Function` object passed accepts just one argument, accesses only the element, (lambda parameter named `x` in that example).

Here's [a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.0) to the `Select` method documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at this particular overload of [LINQ .Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) method. As mentioned above, `i` is just an (**zero-based***) index of respective `x` in the sequence.

Coming back to your particular code snippet, it completely disregards `x` and uses `i` to generate a (**one-based**) value that ends up translating into an XML node. So if you, say, have your

```
var someArray = Enumerable.Range(9999,5); // I'm just generating some big numbers here, you can do the same with strings or objects - it doesn't matter.
```

and run the code you will get something like this:

```
<entry>
  <field name="Option">1</field>
</entry>

<entry>
  <field name="Option">2</field>
</entry>

<entry>
  <field name="Option">3</field>
</entry>

<entry>
  <field name="Option">4</field>
</entry>

<entry>
  <field name="Option">5</field>
</entry>
```