# "Sequence contains no matching element" C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I'm making an application which has `Container`'s with `X`, `Y` and `Z` properties. These containers go in a `Ship`. All the containers are either normal, `Cooled` or `Valuable`. The requirements for valuable is that the X -1 and X + 1 are empty. So basically the containers next to the valuable Container must be empty. And when they are empty I want it to return the `Container` in between.

I pre-made a `List<Container>` with `X`, `Y` and `Z`.

```
public void ConstructShip()
{
    for (int x = 1; x < widthX + 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y < lengthY + 1; y++)
        {
             for (int z = 1; z < heightZ + 1; z++)
             {
                 SortedContainers.Add(new Container(x, y, z, true, false, false, 0)); //xyz, (bool)empty, (bool)valuable, (bool)cooled, weight
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Question: I am trying to make the method `CheckValuableAndReturnPlace()` return an empty container where the coordinates of the other `Container`'s `X - 1` and `X + 1` are `Empty` and not `Valuable` too.

```
 private Container CheckValuableAndReturnPlace()
 {
    Container freeContainer = SortedContainers
    .First(c => c.X > 0 && c.X <= WidthX && c.Empty && c.Z <= HeightZ &&
    SortedContainers.First(c2 => c2.X == c.X - 1).Empty &&
    SortedContainers.First(c2 => c2.X == c.X + 1).Empty &&
    !SortedContainers.First(c2 => c2.X == c.X - 1).Valuable &&
    !SortedContainers.First(c2 => c2.X == c.X + 1).Valuable)
    .FirstOrDefault();

    if (freeContainer != null)
    {
       return freeContainer;
    }

    return new Container();
}
```

For clarification: I want an `Empty` `Container`(which, all of them in the list already are), where the sides, so X -1 and X +1 are `Empty` too. Or if the place is X = 1 than only X = 2 needs to be empty and non-valuable or X = MaxXLength than only X = MaxXlength - 1 needs to be empty and non-valuable

The Unit test:

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void Initialize()
{
    Ship ship = new Ship(4, 3, 3); //lengthX, widthY, heightZ

    for (int x = 1; x < 5; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y < 4; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 1; z < 4; z++)
            {
                ship.SortedContainers.Add(new Container(x, y, z, true, false, false, 0));
            }
        }
    }
}

[TestMethod()]
public void CheckValuableAndReturnPlaceTest_Working()
{
    Container freeContainer = ship.CheckValuableAndReturnPlace();
    Container expectedContainer = new Container(1, 1, 1, true, false, false, 0);

    Assert.AreEqual(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(expectedContainer), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(freeContainer));
}
```

Last EDIT:

Sorry my question was this vague, I tried my hardest not to give excess information that wasn't needed, but I figured it out. Thanks for the one guy for trying to give me an answer :p.

Comment: `SortedContainerStacks.Where((c, i) => c.X > 0 && c.X < SortedContainerStacks.Count - 1 && SortedContainerStacks[c.X - 1].Empty && SortedContainerStacks[c.X + 1].Empty).FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: What does the `i` mean? @GSerg

Comment: Can you share the type of `X`, or in a better way, the `Container` class? Apart from that, I could not get your logic here `c => c.X - 1 == c.Empty && c => c.X + 1 == c.Empty`. It feels sth like true when *zero equals to two*.

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai https://stackoverflow.com/q/59258472/11683

Comment: Have you thought about the edge cases? If `slot[0]` is of type `valuable`, then looking at `slot[-1]` will give an `Index out of range` error instead of its status. Similar for the last slot.

Comment: @GSerg Damn, that might actually work...

Comment: GSerg's suggestion seems quite good actually, and looks like it handles edge cases, but it will always say that the first and last container are **not** valuable. You might want to clarify in your specs if you want them to be valuable if their only neighbour is empty or not. Also, instead of using `FirstOrDefault` and then checking if it's `null`, you could use `Any`

Comment: Also I'm not sure that your current code compiles, as `c` is already used (it's the parameter `CheckValuableAll(Container c)`) so it can't be used here `.FirstOrDefault(c =>` and even if it compiles, it's highly confusing both for you and for us.

Comment: @GSerg Wait...does `SortedContainerStacks[c.X -1]` return a `Container` where `X = X - 1`? Because when I look at it it looks like it returns the `Container` where index  is equal to `c.X - 1` which doesn't per se return the initial thing I said, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai I assumed your `SortedContainerStacks` is sorted by X, but otherwise yes, I made a typo. I meant `(c, i) => i > 0 && i < SortedContainerStacks.Count - 1 && SortedContainerStacks[i - 1].Empty && SortedContainerStacks[i + 1].Empty`. That again may not be what you want, depending on how the `i` and the `c.X` are related.

Comment: This question is unclear to me - you refer to an error in the title, then you talk about "returning" a Container but present a void method, then describe a failing test but don't show the test. I think putting more effort into clarifying the question would help much more than adding a bounty.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh sorry, I edited my post a lot and forgot to change the title.

Comment: I'm afraid there's still way too much we don't know here. What's FilteredContainers? What are all those Container constructor arguments? Which LINQ call fails? At the moment we've got a partial code dump, but without much sign of what you've done to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Well...the whole LINQ call fails. `SortedContainers` is a `List` with pre-made containers that are all empty. How do you diagnose the problem?

Comment: Are you going to eventually want to expand your definition of "sides" to refer to any container bordering the current container on the x, y, or z axis?  Additionally, based on your description, you can have a container that is both empty and valuable?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming there is more to this question than the title. But if the error mentioned in your title is stopping you, please see this stack post.
[Sequence contains no matching element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994336/sequence-contains-no-matching-element)

If I understand correctly, you want to find the first container where it AND its neighbors are all empty and not valuable. I can't quite grasp why, but that seems to be what your post describes.

You mention wanting to find all the containers where the sides also meet these requirements but then only reference the x direction.

> I want an Empty Container(which, all of them in the list already are), where the sides, so X -1 and X +1 are Empty too.

I am following the words("sides") not the logic(only x mentioned) so far since you are asking for advice on the logic.

If i were you, i would rely on a little extra encapsulation to clean up this issue. Separate sorting the boxes and tracking their position. One way you could do this looks kind of like this.

```
public class ContainerGrid{
    public List<List<List<Container>>> Locations = new List<List<List<Container>>>();

    public List<Container> OrderedList;//you can keep sorting the containers and their current locations separate but still cleanly managed this way.

    public bool IsEmpty(int x, int y, int z){
        //interpreting what you said about needing to be empty and not valuable to be viable. 
        return containers[x][y][z].empty && !containers[x][y][z].valuable;
    }

    public bool IsEmptyAndNeighborsEmpty(int x, int y, int z){
        //i am unsure if you intended sides to be only in the x direction 
        //or if that was just a part of how you explained it in the question
        return IsEmpty(x,y,z) 
          && IsEmpty(x-1,y,z) && IsEmpty(x+1,y,z);
        //&& IsEmpty(x,y-1,z) && IsEmpty(x,y+1,z);
        //&& IsEmpty(x,y,z-1) && IsEmpty(x,y,z+1);
    }
    public bool HasLocation(int x, int y, int z){
        return Locations[x]!=null && Locations[x][y] != null && Locations[x][y][z]!=null;
    }
    public bool Add(Container container){
        if(!HasLocation(container.x,container.y,container.z)){
            if(Locations[container.x]==null)
                AddAt<List<List<Container>>>(Locations, container.x, new List<List<Container>>(), false);
            if(Locations[container.x][container.y]==null)
                AddAt<List<Container>>(Locations[container.x], container.y, new List<Container>(), false);
            if(Locations[container.x][container.y][container.z]==null)
                AddAt<Container>(Locations[container.x][container.y], container.z, container, true);
            OrderedList.Add(container);
        }else return false;
    }

    public bool AddAt<T>(List<T> list, int index, T value, bool nullUntil){
        while(list.Count<=index+1) list.add(nullUntil ? null : value);
        list[index]=value;
    }
}
```

There are a lot of ways to encapsulate higher dimensional arrays. and i cannot discern from the context of your question what would be best.

If you intend to model this like a ship yard where the boxes are (theoretically) in a grid pattern and you want to check the neighbors that way, then a three dimensional list is probably the way to go.

if you want a flat grid with each vertical stack of containers as its own list, you can do that too, its all arbitrary and only matters based on what you want to use it for.

but as it stands you can check the emptiness and lack there of as simply as

```
public ContainerGrid ShipYard;
public Container FindFirstEmptyContainer(){
    return ShipYard.OrderedList.FirstOrDefault(x=>ShipYard.IsEmptyAndNeighborsEmpty(x.x,x.y,x.z));
}
```

ordering the list as you please, but still maintaining the same spacial relationships.

Does that answer what you are asking about? Could you clarify anything that is not being covered by this answer?

Comment: I solved it, but since everyone says my question wasn't clear enough. I don't think I deserve a well thought out answer by someone else, but since you're the only one that provided me with a well-thought out looking answer I'll give my points to you. And I'll just delete the post, because I already figured out the way I wanted to do it.